# UISearchBar with ScopeBar in Modal Form Sheet

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, storyboard, uisearchbar

My ViewController is a custom `UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>`. I have set up the UISearchBar to display a scope bar.

I instantiate the view controller once and then show the same view on demand via `[self presentModalViewController:mySearchController fromView:self.view];`

Now, when I configure the view controller to be displayed as a form sheet, the scope bar appears only the first time the view is shown. The next time the scope bar is not displayed.

Displaying the view as a page sheet works fine. However in this case I observe that the first time the scope bar is already in place, while thereafter it is animated into the search bar as soon as it becomes the first responder.

I fiddled around with the view and controller settings in the inspector without any success.

What is causing this behavior?

How can I make the scope bar appear in the form sheet the next time I am showing the view?

Is there a way to prevent the UISearchBar from going into a different state when its view is hidden/redisplayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the scope bar titles in search `delegate` for begin editing and make it `nil` when the search ends. And add the `showScopeBar` method right after this method. Try and check if that helps.

For eg:-

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar { 
  [searchBar setScopeButtonTitles:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Title1", @"Title2", nil]];
  [searchBar setShowsScopeBar:YES];
  //...
}
```

And in `didEndEditing`,

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
  [searchBar setScopeButtonTitles:nil];
  [searchBar setShowsScopeBar:NO];
  //..
}
```

In addition to this, whenever you want to display the scopebar you can use the above lines to show and hide it.

Comment: Wee... Until now, I had set up the scope bar titles in interface builder. Doing it programmatically like you suggested did not solve the issue, BUT: I set the titles to different values and BINGO, it worked. Then I changed back to the proper values, and it was broken again. So what's going on? I cleaned the project, deleted the caches and reset the simulator and still the same behavior. For my original values and also some slight modifications: no-no; For other values: fine. Sth. strange is going on underneath. So in a fresh project your solution prob. works. Any ideas why this is necessary?

Comment: I am not sure about that behavior. Try to remove the title set in IB and do it only programmatically in this case. That might be the issue.

Comment: Yes, I did remove the titles already from IB and cleaned caches after that. Still no luck. Anyway, I have added spaces to the title strings (`@" XYZ "` instead of `@"XYZ"`) which solves my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Setting a title like this always worked for me. Haven't heard about your issue. If it worked for you, could you please vote me up. That should help other folks trying to do the same thing :)

Comment: I'd gladly upvote you if you could explain to me the strange behavior I observed, which was part of my question. My problem still is not solved as all I have is a dirty workaround. You really should be content with the bounty. Thanks for your help, anyway.

Comment: It is actually difficult to predict without seeing your project. All I can assume is that still somewhere your old titles are present and it is still causing issue. Otherwise adding a space wont fix it. Anyways thanks for accepting. Couldn't see any bounty though as you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the conclusion I have come to, too. I've tried to reproduce the behavior in a toy project, without success. I couldn't even observe my original issue with the modal view. All I can say is, the titles are not stored in any place  transparent to the XCode user, and that deleting the caches in `~/Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData/` and cleaning project does not fix. Double checked all connections and code. Nothing strange. I consider this a deep lying bug in XCode that too seldom pops up to be relevant and which now I have a fix for. No more desires. Thanks for the help.